# Error while running Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly

Getting an error while running quickly app:

```
Creating project directory sata
Creating bzr repository and committing
Launching your newly created project!

(sata:2701): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' is not installed

Congrats, your new project is setup! cd /home/blacksaint/sata/ to start hacking.
```

Actually after this the app should pop - up but it really doesn't do so!

Comment: i have this error too !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Xubuntu or Kubuntu? The ERROR message is due to missing GNOME configuration schemas, and something in quickly is apparently trying to read a setting in that schema. The missing schema is installed by the `gsettings-desktop-schemas` package. If you install it and re-run the quickly command to create your app, you should no longer see the error message.

Comment: it says it is already installed !!

Comment: I am getting the same error as the original poster and I just tried to install gesttings-desktop-schemas and it also says it is already installed.

Comment: Did you try `apt-get install --reinstall gsettings-desktop-schemas` then? If that doesn't work, then please file a bug, because it likely is one.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because I was in the /home folder (not /home/elijah) which root owned, this caused me to run quickly with sudo which in turn caused the folder it created to be owned by root. You should be running `quickly create ubuntu-application jotty` in your home folder without sudo, then it should work. This assumes you have gsettings-desktop-schemas installed with `sudo apt-get install gsettings-desktop-schemas`.

tldr;

```
cd ~/
quickly create ubuntu-application jotty
```