# Why is my Quickly app full of fail?

Tags: quickly

I tried to use [quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly) on Ubuntu 12.04 to create an application, but it does not behave as described in that linked page. I don't get a popup when creating the application (see error below).

```
% quickly create ubuntu-application foo
Creating project directory foo
Creating bzr repository and committing
Launching your newly created project!

(foo:16847): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' is not installed

Congrats, your new project is setup! cd /tmp/foo/ to start hacking.
```

It creates a project, but when I try to run, it crashes and burns:

```
% cd foo 
% quickly run

(foo:22639): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' is not installed
```

Is this because I'm not using gnome-shell? What can I do to get a working project?

(**Edit**: As a side note, I'd be willing to debug this myself, but I don't even get a traceback. What do I have to do to get quickly to give me a traceback?)

Comment: The output you've posted doesn't show you using the `quickly run` command to run your project. Is there a reason you're not using it?

Comment: @GarryCairns: Sorry, I've edited to show the output from `quickly run` instead.

Comment: Are you using a non-gnome desktop interface? If so you might be asking the same question as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154615/error-while-running-quickly).

Comment: @GarryCairns: I'm running gnome with i3 (not the default gnome-shell / unity / whatever). I have `gsettings-desktop-schemas` installed (i.e. the answer to that other question), but I did a dpkg-reconfigure on that package and it still fails.

Comment: After doing `cp /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/* data/glib-2.0/schemas`, it seems to be happier about the schemas. The app runs, but I'm getting all kinds of warnings like this: `Could not load image '../media/foo.svg': Couldn't recognize the image file format for file` (the file exists and is an SVG). Also: `Could not find the icon 'gtk-missing-image'. The 'hicolor' theme was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.`, but I have `hicolor-icon-theme` installed. It feels like there's an environment variable or search path that I'm missing...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which process normally sets these variables in the environment, but when I set them in my startup, the errors in my question go away:

```
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-gnome:/etc/xdg
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

I'm still getting these warnings at app runtime:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `Window' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `FooWindow' can't be set after construction
  Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
```